# Eu decido que a pergunta não é boa, e não deixo a comunidade decidir?

Tags: debate, comunidade, pergunta-específica, perguntas-fechadas

Eu acredito que [Herança com interface](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21157/6026) não é ruim ao ponto de suspender, e acredito também que deveria ser uma coisa coletiva?

Gostaria de saber o motivo real da suspensão da questão?

Comment: O motivo está explicado nas respostas. Peço a todos os usuários que passarem por aqui que manifestem suas opiniões através de votos, respostas ou comentários e, se desejarem, reabram a questão.

Comment: Desculpa @utluiz um texto padrão como resposta ... e a mesma coisa de ir no banco e pegar o formulário amarelo!

Comment: Estou chamando as pessoas a votarem e mostrando onde está o botão da "urna eletrônica" para isso. O texto não tem como ser padrão pois não é nada que eu ou alguém tenha escrito anteriormente.

Comment: Se um moderador acha que o fechamento é *garantido*, tem direito a fazê-lo pois recebeu poderes para tal.

Comment: +1 por levantar a questão. mas concordo com o bfvaretto.

Comment: Uma ideia: se você acha que *o tópico* levantado na pergunta é bom, ainda que concorde que *a pergunta em si* [na forma como está] é ruim, por que não abrir outra pergunta? Faça uma pergunta artificial, no formato adequado, e se quiser até mesmo dê uma auto-resposta. Aí sim, se *a comunidade* de fato concordar que a pergunta é boa e merece continuar no site, ela vai permanecer. P.S. não se preocupe por ser duplicata, já que **a outra** é que deveria ser marcada como duplicata desta; é comum se criar "perguntas canônicas" pra problemas comuns *a posteriori*...

Answer (score 12):

Eu tomei a decisão de suspender a pergunta porque ela parecia um beco-sem-saída:

- As informações na pergunta são insuficientes para permitir uma resposta precisa (sem o código-fonte das classes e da interface, não dá para dizer qual é o problema exato, embora seja possível supor as causas).
- "Supor as causas" foi o que o bigown fez nos comentários, e ele tinha razão: a assinatura do método na interface não batia com a assinatura do método na classe.
- A troca de comentários com o bigown levou o autor a resolver seu problema sozinho, como se vê neste [comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/21157/heran%c3%a7a-com-interface?noredirect=1#comment38276_21157):

  > Foi erro meu, a interface estava recebendo, como parâmetro, um int? e não um int. Obrigado pela ajuda.
- A "resposta" portanto foi dada pelo próprio autor no comentário. E só ele poderia dar essa resposta com precisão, já que as informações da pergunta são insuficientes para outra pessoa chegar a essa conclusão.

Foi essa a minha linha de raciocínio para o fechamento. A alternativa seria pedir ao autor que complemente a pergunta, mas o bigown já havia feito isso e não foi atendido. Dessa maneira, considerei que a pergunta não iria ajudar outros usuários na forma atual, pois só permitiria respostas especulativas.

Vou aguardar as opiniões da comunidade e dos outros moderadores sobre a minha decisão. Se a maioria considerar que eu errei, desfaço o fechamento sem problemas.

Comment: Outro fator @bfavareto tem questões piores se intervenção nenhum dos moderadores

Comment: @HarryPotter Sinalize-as.

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/21164/conexao-reiniciada

Comment: @HarryPotter Ora, basta votar para fechar. Nem é preciso de moderadores para tomar esse tipo de decisão. Em pouco tempo estará em suspenso.

Comment: @HarryPotter Essa eu não vou fechar porque ninguém pediu mais informações ao autor ainda, e não é uma pergunta já resolvida como a que está em debate aqui. A comunidade pode decidir fechar como "não é claro...", mas *eu* não vou fazer isso sem ter havia diálogo com o autor antes. Então é um caso diferente, que fica na mão da comunidade, pelo menos por enquanto. Se estivesse resolvida ou abandonada, aí sim eu fecharia.

Answer (score 8):

A pergunta descreve um problema A (e hierarquia das classes) e afirma que ele não funciona. A reposta é que não há nenhum problema em A, tudo está certo. O autor descobre que o problema real está em B (a assinatura da função) e que é totalmente não relacionado. O autor resolve o problema B.

Resultado: A pergunta não possui resposta possível além de "está certo". Se ela, por exemplo, contivesse mais informação como o código para reproduzir, a resposta poderia apontar para o problema B, mas isso não é possível pois não há informação suficiente. Como é uma pergunta que não há como responder, deve ser fechada. Ela não descreve nem um problema nem nada útil para outros.

O fechamento foi correto.

Comment: Até posso concordo, mas, o coletivo não decidiu isso... foi imposição e outra, é um questão que pode servir como tutorial, uma boa edição pode favorecer a resposta!

Comment: @HarryPotter Uma ação de um moderador não é uma imposição. É meramente uma decisão de um membro da comunidade agindo em um caso que ele considerou "obvio". Se ele estiver errado, pode-se argumentar (como bem fez abrindo a pergunta aqui no meta). Apenas junte argumentos para mostrar que a pergunta deveria estar aberta. Assim outros podem concordar com você e votar, é natural.

Comment: tem perguntas piores, que não tem intervenção nenhuma dos moderadores, fica a dica... argumentos a questão já tem e eu acredito que alterando alguma coisa poderia servir como tutorial.

Comment: @HarryPotter O texto da sua pergunta não contém argumentos muito detalhados. Sugiro postar sua própria resposta aqui defendendo a pergunta e justificando por que deva ficar aberta. O fato de existirem perguntas abertas que deveriam estar fechadas não justifica que qualquer pergunta deva ser deixada aberta.

Comment: @bfavaretto a minha pergunta é boa sim!, ela vai tornar o site mais pra comunidade, posso ter votos negativos, podem dar upvoter para o pessoal mais velho, mas, o que você fez ta errado... e você mesmo disse no seu discurso que não iria intervir muito e deixar a comunidade tal obrigação e somente casos muito ruins que iria intervir.

Comment: @HarryPotter Lembre-se de que **você não é a comunidade sozinho**. Se mais usuários estiverem dispostos a reabrir a questão, ela será aberta, inevitavelmente.

Comment: Lembre @utluiz que a minha pergunta disse comunidade... eu não to querendo isso, ser o sozinho, mas, o que aconteceu foi decidido sozinho, preste atenção por favor

Comment: @HarryPotter Eu não estou dizendo que a sua pergunta é ruim. Ela levanta a discussão, o que é ótimo, mas não argumenta com consistência em favor da reabertura. E está certo, o lugar para fazer isso seria uma resposta mesmo. Poste a sua e deixe a comunidade julgá-la como eu fiz aqui.

Answer (score 7):

Sim, a comunidade tem todo o direito de decidir.

Do meu ponto de vista, nosso trabalho como moderadores não é o de decidir unilateralmente, mas de "manter a ordem" e "dar um empurrãozinho" em casos óbvios.

**O que isso quer dizer?**

Por "manter a ordem" quero dizer que nós tratamos de casos excepcionais e abusos.

Por "dar um empurrãozinho" quero dizer que podemos agir em caso de perguntas que obviamente deveriam ser fechadas, mas ainda não tiveram a quantidade de votos ou atenção suficientes.

Lógico que esse "obviamente" é subjetivo, por isso tentamos agir com cautela.

No entanto, na pergunta em questão ficou óbvio que **não existia um problema real**.

Comment: A questão é que não tinha votos negativos, e acredito que o pessoal queria saber o motivo, erro foi mesmo, mas, com uma boa edição ficaria como tutorial

Comment: Qual "boa edição"? Não podemos inventar código para colocar na pergunta!

Comment: Não é inventar @bfavaretto é melhorar, você mesmo já fez muito isso.

Comment: @HarryPotter Não há problemas algum em reabrir a pergunta **se** o OP colocar o código que estava errado e possibilitasse uma resposta adequada para a questão. Como ela está agora, não existe um problema real.

Comment: @utluiz o OP resolveu teóricamente seu problema e já nem fez interação, é outro problema